# React Context value updated is not reflecting in previous screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context, use-context

I have react native app with navigation from A -> B.

```
//TestContext.js
export const TestContext = createContext('initial value');

//B.js
  const {myVal,changeMyVal} = useContext(TestContext);
return(
<View>
    <Button
            onPress={() => {
              changeMyVal('new value')
              console.log(myVal); // Prints 'new value'
            }}>
</View>
);

//A.js
  const {myVal} = useContext(TestContext);
return(
<View>
    <Button
            onPress={() => {
              console.log(myVal); // Prints 'initial value'
            }}>
</View>
);
```

When I come back from B to A and print context value still I am getting *initial value*. How can get updated value then in A since I am not re-rendering when coming back from B?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please show the component where you use `<TestContext.Provider>`. You click on [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65636885/edit) to add details to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) doesn't get back an updater function as the useState hook does. If you want to update your state from the consumer just give an updater function from the provider such as,

```
const ContextShared = createContext({ value: "", updater: () => null });
    ...
    const [value, updater] = useState("initialValue");
    ...
    <ContextShared.Provider value={{ value, updater }}>
        <Component1 />
        <Component2 />
      </ContextShared.Provider>


    function Component1() {
    const { value } = useContext(ContextShared);
    ...
    }
    
    function Component2() {
        const { updater } = useContext(ContextShared);
        function handleClick() {
        updater("updated from page 2");
      }
    
      return <div onClick={handleClick}>Page 2 </div>;
    }
```

[Live working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/updater-fn-context?file=src/App.js)

Comment: Since I don't have the enough background in React Native, I cannot help you any longer :(.